# Please explain the output of this simple C program

Tags: c, associativity

```
int i = 2, j = 3, k, l ;
float a, b ;
k = i / j * j ;
l = j / i * i ;
a = i / j * j ;
b = j / i * i ;
printf( "%d %d %f %f", k, l, a, b ) ;
}
```

it is a simple c program from yashwant kanetkar but i could not relate to the answer .
if we compile this program the output which i am getting is

```
0 2 0.00000 2.00000
```

this is a very simple program but i am not able to explain the output may be i am getting confused with the associativity.
both / and * have L to R associativity and only / has unambiguous left operand (necessary condition for L to R associativity) it is performed earlier. but the answer is different in that case .

Comment: First kick out that rubbish book out of your desk and then pick some good book/tutorial.

Comment: The associativity or precedence is as you expected, the thing you are confused is **integer division**.

Answer (score 1):

It is [simple associativity of the operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), nothing complex.

I think it's the ["integer division"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/2173917) property which is making you confused.

1. `k = i / j * j ;` answer 0, because of integer division first (`i / j` == 0).
2. `l = j / i * i ;` answer 2, because of integer division first. (`j / i` == 1)
3. `a = i / j * j ;` answer 0, (promoted to `float`) because of integer division first, as I mentioned earlier.
4. `b = j / i * i ;`, answer 2, (promoted to `float`) because of integer division  first, alo mentioned earlier.

---

Note: [A gentle version of what Mr. Haccks said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118910/please-explain-the-output-of-this-simple-c-program/31119009#comment50250942_31118910) : Please avoid referring that particular book.

Comment: `/` and `*` are of same precedence therefore associativity is from left to right. (Down vote is not mine BTW)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes, that was wrong, I updated with the code snippet.

Comment: @haccks yes, it's left to right, I linked the page, also. :-)